# Ajax cache: false in PhoneGap 2.1 loading error

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, caching, cordova

I found that the ajax call loading problem occurs when `cache: false` is added. I have tested it on three mobile phones: Samsung Galaxy SIII (Android 4.1.2), Sony Xperia P (Android 4.0.4) and LG (Android 4.0.3). Only SIII has no problem. Sony and LG phones just keep loading when calling ajax. How to solve it?
This following code is the ajax call mentioned:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:  serviceURL ,
        async: true, 
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
             .......
        }),
        success: function(data) {
        ......
        }
    });
```

If I removed `cache: false`, the three phones run the ajax normally.
The mobile app uses PhoneGap 2.1, Backbone.js, Jquerymobile 1.2 and Jquery 1.8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pages fetched with POST are never cached, so the cache and ifModified options in jQuery.ajaxSetup() have no effect on these requests.